# magento 2 : Enable maintenance mode frontend only?

Tags: magento2

How to enable maintenance mode for frontend only.

I used `php bin/magento maintenance:enable`

but it close both frontend and backend .

Answer (score 3):

If yow want to prevent customers to use the site while you carry on making changes in the admin you could whitelist your IP(s):

```
$ bin/magento maintenance:enable --ip="{your-ip-here}"
```

Answer (score 0):

php bin/magento maintenance:enable --ip="{your-ip-here}" works

actually, it allows to get access of that particular IP user, it does not like frontend down and admin work but it allows both.